# how to overflow element to be on top on another container?

Tags: c#, wpf, position

```
<Window x:Class="TestringWpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="Yellow"></StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Background="Green">
        <Button Margin="0,0,0,10000000000">ABC</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

The above code will gives me the situation below:
[image]

As you can see, the button was declared at the second `StackPanel` and hence no matter how I set the margin, the button couldn't go out of the green background. I'm wondering what can I do to declare the button in `<StackPanel Grid.Row="1">` and appear partly on `<StackPanel Grid.Row="0">` .

**In conclusion, how to make an element overflow in it's container and overlap on another container? Is it possible?**

Comment: This is something wrong here I guess. You want control `Button` to be part/drawn on another control `Grid.Row=0`. This is strange... If `Button` should be the part of top row - may be it should be there already without setting those strange `Margin` values....

Comment: @Jasper: Nothing is weird here, I was trying to place 2/3 of the button on `Grid.Row=0` and the remaining on `Grid.Row=1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option would be a `RenderTransform`.

```
<Button Content="ABC">
    <Button.RenderTransform>
         <TranslateTransform Y="-50"></TranslateTransform>
    </Button.RenderTransform>
</Button>
```